# How to remove icons from ''all applications''?

Tags: uninstall, icons

I installed Star Wars: Battlefront 2 through Wine and then I uninstalled it. But icons for that game are still in my *all applications* panel. There is icon for another game also.

I want to remove those icons. How do I do that ? 
I am using Linux Ubuntu GNOME (14.10).

Answer (score 8):

Certain desktops come with a menu editor, in which you could remove the entries.

Else, open the directory `.local/share/applications/` in a terminal or file browser and remove the .desktop files you don't need any longer.

Answer (score 7):

All the applications exist as `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`

To remove a particular entry -

```
cd /usr/share/applications

sudo rm <name-of-application>.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open system settings, then along its top, Privacy.  When you delete recent activity, you delete recently run applications from that section of your "all applications".  In fact it is only because those now deleted programs were recently run that they are listed there at all.

If you examine the function of your "all applications" display more, and come to understand it, you will be less frustrated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem alike an solved. The answer about the intruder icon in the "all applications" that ensures the file responsible is the name of the icon with the extension `.desktop` prove to be correct.

But the `desktop` file is not always in the `/usr/share/applications/ directory`; it could be in another place. So the general way to solve this is as follows:

1. Open "files", go to "other locations" at the end of the list, click "computer".
2. Click the search button (look for the magnifying glass); the word "computer" will disappear and will wait for your input.
3. Enter the name of the icon and add ".desktop" to it, press enter key.
4. You should find the  file and the name of the directory where it is located.
5. Right click the file found and select "Open Item Location"
6. In that directory you might find several files, but the one that you are interested in is usually selected by default.
7. You may just delete the file or use the long way of removing it from terminal.

IMPORTANT: after you done everything, **restart** your device so that the changes are made in "all applications"

Answer (score -1):

it is too easy but it is looks too hard really. I searched everywhere how to do it but found no accurate answers at all.
What I did was:

1. Open the files application
2. Click on the search bar and search the name of the application

Surely you will find the application name with `.desktop` extension. Delete that file completely but if it is not showing than you will surely see a folder with the name of the application.  In that folder you will see the application with `.desktop` extension. Delete that and it's done.